# ios 8 framework back compatibility

Tags: ios7, ios8

Following apple's new ios8 framework support, I wanted to know if apple also provides background compatibility with those frameworks on ios7 devices.

If so, what is required to achieve this back compatibility? If no, is there any best practise suggested for this situation?

Comment: I'm running into same issue.  The advice I get is that You need to create a new iOS 8 framework.  The latest update does not support earlier frameworks.  I am guessing that the newer Universal Frameworks will run on older devices but your framework needs to be updated.